# R - How to remove "c(" from list being written to file

Tags: r

This is one of those things that is very hard to search for on google...

I have a dataframe:

```
x=c("a", "b", "c")
y=list(c(1,2,3), c("f","g"), c(1,"r","$"))
df = as.data.frame(x)
df$y = y
```

I tranform it as such and print it to a `.txt`:

```
p = sprintf('{"name":"%s", "import": [%s]}', df$x, df$y)
write(p, "p.txt")
```

The output print with the `c()` notation:

```
{"name":"a", "import": [c(1, 2, 3)]}
{"name":"b", "import": [c("f", "g")]}
{"name":"c", "import": [c("1", "r", "$")]}
```

How can I remove this so that it prints like:

```
{"name":"a", "import": [1, 2, 3]}
{"name":"b", "import": ["f", "g"]}
{"name":"c", "import": ["1", "r", "$"]}
```

Comment: Are you trying to generate JSON data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks fairly straightforward, you just have to use string substitution. So for example these:

```
x=c("a", "b", "c")
y=list(c(1,2,3), c("f","g"), c(1,"r","$"))
df = as.data.frame(x)
df$y = y
p = sprintf('{"name":"%s", "import": [%s]}', df$x, df$y)
p <- gsub("\\[c\\("," \\[",p)
p <- gsub("\\)\\]","\\]",p)
write(p, "p.txt")
```

Comment: Well I _knew_ that you had initially forgotten the escapes and thought I had solved the problem.

Comment: I am happy. Broke 900 :)

Answer (score 2):

Tested:

```
write(gsub("\\[c", "[", p), "p.txt")

{"name":"a", "import": [(1, 2, 3)]}
{"name":"b", "import": [("f", "g")]}
{"name":"c", "import": [("1", "r", "$")]}
```

To also remove the parens:

```
write(gsub("[()]", "",gsub("\\[c", "[", p)), "p.txt")

{"name":"a", "import": [1, 2, 3]}
{"name":"b", "import": ["f", "g"]}
{"name":"c", "import": ["1", "r", "$"]}
```